# Google Cloud Messaging Business setup

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to find out how Google Cloud Messaging should be setup for businesses.

Currently I'm using my private Google account to manage the Google Developer Console and create a GCM project for my application. But what if I where e.g. a consultant agency developing an app for a customer, how would GCM be setup then?

I'm trying to answer the following questions:

- Is there a way to create a Google account for Business that should be used instead?
- Is it still free of charge?
- Should the customer have and manage this account or do I as a developer/provider of the app manage this account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm):

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers to send messages between servers and client apps.

Your Questions:

> Is there a way to create a Google account for Business that should be
>   used instead?

Gcm does not require a special type of Google Account. Once you can create a Project in the Google Developer Console then you can use GCM with that project.

> Is it still free of charge?

Yes it is free, even in business use cases.

> Should the customer have and manage this account or do I as a developer/provider of the app manage this account?

This is up to you, it would depend on what the future relationship between the developer and the owner of the application is.